# How can I get 2560 * 1600 on Win 7 ? MacBook Pro 17 + Dell 30 inch 3008 WFP + Fusion 3

Tags: windows-7, macos, macbook, resolution, vmware-fusion

I run VM Ware Fusion 3 on a Mac Book Pro 17 hooked to a Dell 30 inch screen

I **CAN** manage to get a Resolution of 2560 * 1600 on Mac OS X(MacBook Pro), but can't on Win 7 (on the exact same MacBook Pro)

The highest resolution I can get on MS Win 7 is 2048 * 1536 (and I want to be able to set it to 2560 * 1600 to fully enjoy the real estate of my 30 inch screen!)

I have searched the KB, and found an article which mentionned that I should add the following lines in the vmx file (which I did)
The lines are the very bottom of the vmx file

```
svga.maxWidth = "2560"
svga.maxHeight = "1600" 
svga.vramSize = "16384000"
```

KB Article : http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1003&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=63746028&stateId=0%200%2066741566

I did the manipulation describe in the KB above however, I rebooted several times, but I still can't get the correct resolution to show in Windows

Answer (score 1):

All was the required was to install the VM Ware Tools on Windows 7 (using Fusion), the 3 lines I have added above were unnecessary.