# Testing Software on 1366x768 Resolution Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, display, resolution, vmware-fusion

I have a WinForms application (C#). The user is reporting a window cutting issue on her 15 inch laptop screen: Meaning a portion of the window is below the screen. I have made some changes to the application. But I don't have a proper machine to test it out. I have a MacBook Pro 15 inch and a Windows PC with 24 inch monitor.

Is there a way to set the virtual machine (Windows 10) to run with the specific resolution setting (1366x768) to replicate the issue if exists.

Comment: Install whatever Guest additions there are for your VM software, then simply resize the VM window to the resolution you want.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks.... Actually I need to uncheck 'use Retina display' option in fusion,resize the window or set the resolution within the virtual machine(in windows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get 2560 \* 1600 on Win 7 ? MacBook Pro 17 + Dell 30 inch 3008 WFP + Fusion 3](https://superuser.com/questions/104429/how-can-i-get-2560-1600-on-win-7-macbook-pro-17-dell-30-inch-3008-wfp-fu)